Issues with Object Initialization after Graphene Upgrade (3.0.0)
I've upgraded graphene version from v2.1.8 to v3.0.0 and I'm encountering issues with object initialization. After upgrading, my ObjectType subclasses are no longer properly initialized, and I'm getting errors when creating instances.
Here's an example of my code:
from graphene import ObjectType, Int

class TestObjectType(ObjectType):
    field1 = Int()
    field2 = Int()

test_instance = TestObjectType(field1=1, field2=2) # this shows a warning "unexpected arguments"

This used to work perfectly fine in graphene v2.1.8
It seems that the __init__ method has been removed in the new implementation, as seen in PR #1157. The ObjectTypeMeta metaclass handles initialization now, but I can't figure out how to properly initialize my fields without explicitly defining an __init__ method.
Also, the breaking change is for private fields. https://github.com/graphql-python/graphene/wiki/v3-release-notes#objecttype-private-fields
But I don't have any private fields in my class.
I am using Python v3.8, django v4.2
